# How to remove variable in img src tag?

Tags: php

I have a sample code:

```
$filename = 'http://thebox.vn/Uploaded/catmy/2013_04_23/couple_t2.jpg?maxwidth=480';
```

And I using this code to remove variable (maxwidth)

```
echo preg_replace('/(\?)$/', '', $filename)
```

=> How to remove variable (maxwidth), how to fix it ?

Comment: How about using a URL parser? http://stackoverflow.com/q/12687790/139010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this

```
$filename = 'http://thebox.vn/Uploaded/catmy/2013_04_23/couple_t2.jpg?maxwidth=480';
echo preg_replace("/\?[a-z]+=\d+/", '', $filename);
```

[**DEMO.**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/vz3QuG)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to *get rid of query*, just do that:

```
$filename = 'http://thebox.vn/Uploaded/catmy/2013_04_23/couple_t2.jpg?maxwidth=480';
$parts = explode("?",$filename);
$filename = $parts[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do:

```
$filename = "http://thebox.vn/Uploaded/catmy/2013_04_23/couple_t2.jpg?maxwidth=480";
$filename = array_shift(explode('?', $filename));
echo $filename;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current regular expression says: replace the last character of `$filename` with the empty string if that last character is the question mark character.

Here is a fixed regular expression that works for your particular example: `/\?maxwidth=.*$/`

There are many other expressions that could do the job for various circumstances. However, perhaps it would be better to use PHP's [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function to split the URL into its various parts and then just discard the parts that you do not care about and merge back into a string. For example:

```
$filename = 'http://thebox.vn/Uploaded/catmy/2013_04_23/couple_t2.jpg?maxwidth=480';

// Parse the filename into parts.
$filename_parsed = parse_url( $filename );

// Merge the parsed filename back into a string,
// discarding any irrelevant parts.
$filename_merged = $filename_parsed[ 'scheme' ] . '://' . $filename_parsed[ 'host' ] . $filename_parsed[ 'path' ];

// Prints: http://thebox.vn/Uploaded/catmy/2013_04_23/couple_t2.jpg
echo $filename_merged;
```